# TinyMCE 4: Plugin-Window - word wrap available?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I try to migrate our custom plugins from TinyMCE 3 to 4.
In some cases there is some text in the plugin's window to describe how to use it.
Fiddle example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Hndaab/1

So if the text is very long, the window width increases until some parts are out of the viewport.
How can i tell the WindowManager to use automatic word wrapping for my labels?

I already tried to define a width for the window. And in another plugin i found a param "multiline". Both didn't solve my problem.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to accomplish something similar for mobile commpability where the windows are to large for the viewport and so far the closest i've gotten is to set the css for .mce-window to

```
.mce-window {... max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}
```

maybe that will be enought to fix your specific problem, even if I still have some ways to go for it to fluidly only fill out the available viewport space on all other windows.